# How to create user with role(s) through REST service?

Tags: 7, users, services

I could able to create a new user by the following JSON format.(Using POSTER add-on to post this data to REST service.)

```
{
   "name":"user34",
   "pass":"3323",
   "mail":"sample@example.com",
   "status":"1"
}
```

My question is how to create a user with specific role. I tried with the following JSON format.

```
{
   "name":"user35",
   "pass":"pwds3",
   "mail":"sample2@example.com",
   "status":"1",
   "roles":{
      "2":"authenticated user",
      "4":"moderator"
   }
}
```

but the response gives the following error

> ["An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator."]

Comment: The user performing the action MUST have "administer users" and "administer permissions"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After many trials, I was able to resolve my issue

Here is the JSON format to create user with role.

```
{
   "name":"user343",
   "pass":"kes35@r4",
   "mail":"user343@sample.com",
   "status":"1",
   "roles":[
      "4"
   ]
}
```

To assign multiple roles,

```
{
   "name":"user344",
   "pass":"kes344@r4",
   "mail":"user344@sample.com",
   "status":"1",
   "roles":[
      "3",
      "4"
   ]
}
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Which is the url to create new user in poster

Comment: https://my_url/rest_endpoint/user and posted via rest client (ARC) of chrome

Comment: Can you list which all processes can do by through rest client ??

Answer (score 0):

This helped!

I used the request URL `endpoint/user/register` and passed headers `content-type` as **application/json** and X-CSRF-TOKEN which I got by login to the system.

Thanks.

Comment: When registering a new user how would you get a X-CSRF-TOKEN? you mentioned that you got token by login to the system, but user should be registered first before that can login.