# Services can not create an user with role

Tags: services

I follow this answer [How to create user with role(s) through REST service?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102487/how-to-create-user-with-role-through-rest-service-drupal-7)

```
{"name":"user343","pass":"kes35@r4","mail":"user343@sample.com","status":"1", "roles":["4"]}
```

But When I check the created user, It role still is '2' (authenticated user)

Answer (score 0):

Just install `Auto Assign Role` Module.

Then use this following json code:

```
{"name":"user3431","pass":"kes35@r4","mail":"user343@sample.com","status":"1", "user_roles":{"6"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue occured with me. I used [rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)
module to assign a role on user account creation based on certain field data.Hope it helps