# Cannot assign roles creating User through REST endpoint

Tags: 7, users, services

Sidenote, already seen this page, doesn't seem to help: [How to create user with role(s) through REST service?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102487/how-to-create-user-with-roles-through-rest-service)

I've setup a new endpoint on my platform to try to allow a 3rd party to create users on the site, I've connected it up and I'm testing it out through a REST client on Firefox. So far it seems to be working fine with the exception of applying the role to the new account.

According to the link pasted above, it needs to be set to:

```
{
  "name": "rest_user_1",
  "mail": "rest_user_1@test.com",
  "pass": "abc123",
  "status": "1",
  "roles": [
    "5",
    "6"
  ]
}
```

But that doesn't work, I've got the debugger enabled, and I can see from the response it seems to be coming back with this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => rest_user_1
            [mail] => rest_user_1@test.com
            [pass] => abc123
            [status] => 1
            [roles] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => 6
                )

        )

)
```

To me it looks like it's assigning the role IDs (5/6) as the values in an array, rather than the keys, so instead I tried writing my body in a different way:

My body at the moment is:

```
{
  "name": "rest_user_2",
  "mail": "rest_user_2@test.com",
  "pass": "abc123",
  "status": "1",
  "roles": {
    "5": "Role 1",
    "6": "Role 2"
  }
}
```

And the response in the log messages looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => rest_user_2
            [mail] => rest_user_2@test.com
            [pass] => abc123
            [status] => 1
            [roles] => Array
                (
                    [5] => Role 1
                    [6] => Role 2
                )

        )

)
```

Which looks like exactly what I'd expect, but yet, still it hasn't applied the roles to my account. Can anyone help?

Comment: And you have read this comment, The user performing the action MUST have "administer users" and "administer permissions"?

Comment: @Jdrupal, which user role does that need to be added to though?

Comment: The user role that shall be able to create users via the REST endpoint.

Comment: @Jdrupal, I think I'm probably missing a step in the whole process then, I'm not particularly familiar with services in general, because at the moment that means applying that access to anonymous users, which is definitely wrong.

Comment: It sounds wrong to me that you will give anonymous users permission to create users on your site, is that correct? In that case everybody could create an administrator and then login as an administrator and crash the site. Only trusted users should be able to create users and define their roles.

Comment: @Jdrupal, exactly, I think I've missed a step because that would be the current solution under my current circumstances. Just to ask a beginner question, would the normal solution to this to have the 3rd party app login to a specific account through the endpoint first, then allow that user account access to the roles it needs, or is this what OAuth can do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95713/discussion-between-jdrupal-and-andrew-morris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For other people reaching this post, the answer to this is to use some kind of authentication on the REST endpoint, that only allows trusted users to create new users.

Otherwise anonymous users would be able to create admins and crash the site.

So this code is correct,

```
"roles": [
  "5",
  "6"
]
```

but the problem is that the user calling the endpoint has to have the `administer permissions` and `administer users` permission to be able to set roles to users.

That can be done by setting a role that has those permissions and also has permission to call the endpoint.

oAuth could be used to do that.